# Android Genymotion audio distorted

Tags: android, audio, emulation, genymotion

I am running my app on the Genymotion emulator and yesterday I ran the program and the audio was working perfectly, however today I checked the audio feature and the result is this deep, slow version of the song. Anybody have any ideas on why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are maybe running this on Lollipop (5.0 or 5.1). This is a known bug that will be solved on the next release. You should not encounter the same problem on other Android versions.